# why do we use KeyValuePair keyword instead of Dictionary<tkey,tvalue> keyword as the type in foreach loop?

Tags: c#

am just learning c# and wanted to use the type instead of var in foreach loop while using the dictionary, but it gave me error when i used Dictionary

```
Dictionary<int, string> names = new Dictionary<int string>();

names[10] = "some test";
names[11] = "another text";

foreach(Dictionary<int,string> name in names)
{
    Console.WriteLine(name);
}
```

Comment: Because the `Dictionary` contains a `KeyValuePair` for each entry (item) in the dictionary. `IDictionary` implements the `IEnumerable` interface, and this is how the `GetEnumerator` function was implemented for Dictionaries.

Comment: Because a Dictionary does not contain Dictionaries inside itself? It only contains entries.

Comment: A tip: Write `foreach(var (myKey, myValue) in names)`. This splits the KeyValuePair into separate variables.

Comment: If a dictionary contained only dictionaries, then those dictionaries would also contain dictionaries. It would be dictionaries all the way down!

Comment: minutiae: `KeyValuePair` is not a "keyword" - it is an identifier; keywords are things like `foreach`, `in`, `new` - they are parts of the *language*, not part of the type-model

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately, the dictionary doesn't *contain multiple dictionaries*; it contains (semantically, at least): multiple key/value pairs - hence that is what `foreach` gives you, via multiple `KeyValuePair<int, string>` values. You can use this without even needing to know about the type:

```cs
foreach (var pair in names)
{
    Console.WriteLine(pair.Key);
    Console.WriteLine(pair.Value);
}
```

(which is identical to `foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> pair in names)`)

or:

```cs
foreach ((var key, var value) in names)
{
    Console.WriteLine(key);
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

(you can also use `var (key, value)` or `(int key, string name)` as the enumerator declaration)